# The asymptotic distribution of the criterion function in M-estimation

Tags: asymptotics, law-of-large-numbers, empirical-processes

Suppose that we are interested in a parameter (or  functional)
$\theta$ attached to the distribution of observations $\left\{ X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}\right\} $.
A popular method for finding an estimator $\hat{\theta}_{n}=\hat{\theta}_{n}(X_{1},\ldots,X_{n})$
is to maximize a criterion function of the type
\begin{equation}
\theta\mapsto M_{n}(\theta)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{\theta}(X_{i})
\end{equation}
Here $m_{\theta}:\mathcal{X}\mapsto\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ are known
functions. An estimator maximizing $M_{n}(\theta)$ over $\Theta$
is called an M-estimator

\begin{equation}
\hat{\theta}_{n}=\arg\max_{\theta\in\Theta}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{\theta}(X_{i})
\end{equation}

There are a lot investigation on the asymptotic behavior of sequences
of M-estimators
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\theta}_{n}-\theta\right)\to^{D}...
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\theta=\arg\max_{\theta\in\Theta}E_{\theta}m_{\theta}(X).
\end{equation}

I want to study the asymptotic distribution of the criterion function,
i.e.
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{\hat{\theta}_{n}}(X_{i})-E_{\theta}m_{\theta}(X)\right)\to^{D}?
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{n}\left(M_{n}(\hat{\theta}_{n})-M(\theta)\right)\to^{D}?
\end{equation}

I read several books, e.g., Asymptotic Statistics by van der Vaart,
but find no comment on this issue.

Note that one can not solve this issue by the Delta theorem, because
$M_{n}(\hat{\theta}_{n})$ depends on the observations, thus it is
not a deterministic function of $\theta$.